# UVM indexing into array by get_type_name

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

Is this possible? Get_type_name is a string. Can't I have an int array and use the name to index in? I get index expression type of illegal.

Obj n1;

int number[100];

n1 = new();

number[n1.get_type_name] = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Long day. Should have declared int number[string]